# How to iterate over a list and link references to related items?

Tags: javascript

Assume I have a list of objects

I want to iterate over this list and link dailyBalance object to it's daily transactions and then add transactions count to dailyBalance object.

I tried to do this by iterating over the list, and if I found an object of type dailyBalance, I pause  the current running loop, then create a nested loop and find objects of type transaction, and break that nested loop as soon as I find another object of type dailyBalance. It should work, but doesn't work as expected.

```js
for (let position = 0; position < data.length; ++position) {
  const item = data[position];
  if (item.type == "dailyBalance") {
    for (let i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data[i].type == "dailyBalance") {
        break;
      } else {
        data[position].txCount = data[position].txCount + 1;
        data[i].balanceRef = data[position];
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
   // B2 - Balance Node 2
   {type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, //txCount 2 //B2,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B2,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B2,
   // B1 - Balance Node 1
   {type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, //txCount 4 //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null } //B1,
]
</script>
```

***Expected output***

```
[
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
  { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 2 }, //txCount 2 //B2,
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: <balance object B2> }, 
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: <balance object B2> }, 
  { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 4 }, //txCount 4 //B1,
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: <balance object B1> }, 
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: <balance object B1> }, 
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: <balance object B1> }, 
  { type: "transaction", balanceRef: <balance object B1> } 
];
```

Comment: @mplungjan Nitesh got it correctly on his answer below, but he forget to link the reference, but I made a change to his code `data[i].balanceRef = data[itemIndex];`. I'm really horrible at explaining algorithms.

Comment: @mplungjan If you can, add it's functional version. I liked your reduce answer, but you deleted it ..

Comment: I undeleted it. If you like it you should vote it up and please please show what the output should look like so I can update my code

Comment: @Nitheesh You can run Nitesh code and yours then compare output because his code correctly output exact format I wanted. I just don't think I can describe JS Objects in plain text.

Comment: @mplungjan I just made edit to your answer to answer what to put to ??? value. I really wish I could type it on ??? fields, but I CAN'T.

Comment: @jeffbRTC What does the `functional style` means?

Comment: @jeffbRTC I think you are just looking for much complex code that you can say "I have did with more advanced operators".You dont neeed to have 1 loop and 3 condition checking to achieve the target. My answer did it with 1 loop and 2 condition checking.

Comment: @jeffbRTC You can check the updated anser for the functional implementation with one loop and 2 condition checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use reduce

Note I test the savedIndex because 0 is falsy so if the array starts with a daily balance the code would fail if I did not test

```js
let savedIndex;
const reduced = data.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  acc.push(cur);
  if (cur.type === "transaction") {
    if (savedIndex != null) {
      acc[savedIndex].txCount++; 
      acc[acc.length-1].balanceRef = acc[savedIndex]; // save a reference to the balance objecct  
      // acc[acc.length-1].balanceRef = savedIndex;   // save the index of the balance object
    }  
  }
  if (cur.type === "dailyBalance") savedIndex = i;
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(reduced)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null },
   {type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, //txCount 2 //B2,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B2,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B2,
   {type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, //txCount 4 //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, //B1,
   {type: "transaction", balanceRef: null } //B1,
]
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop can help you.

**Logic**

- Loop through the data array
- Check `type` of each object
- If `type` is `dailyBalance` keep that index in a variable.
- From the next index onwards increment the `txCount` of the obect with the previousl stored index.
- This will increment the `txCount` of the slected object till next `dailyBalance` is found.
- Also link the `balanceRef` for the next coming nodes with the selected target.

```js
const data = [{ type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }];
let itemIndex = null;
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].type === 'dailyBalance') {
    itemIndex = i;
  }  else if(itemIndex !== null) {
    data[i].balanceRef = data[itemIndex];
    ++data[itemIndex].txCount;
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

**Some functional styles**

**`Array.map` implementation**

```js
const data = [{ type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }];
let referenceNode = null;
const output = data.map((node) => {
  if (node.type === "dailyBalance") {
    referenceNode = node;
  } else if (referenceNode !== null) {
    ++referenceNode.txCount;
    node.balanceRef = referenceNode;
  }
  return node;
});
console.log(output);
```

**`Array.reduce` implementation.**

```js
const data = [{ type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "dailyBalance", txCount: 0 }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }, { type: "transaction", balanceRef: null }];
let referenceNode = null;
const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(curr.type === "dailyBalance") {
    referenceNode = curr;
  } else if (referenceNode !== null) {
    ++referenceNode.txCount;
    curr.balanceRef = referenceNode;
  }
  acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```